# Low-degree polynomial approximation of the piecewise-linear function $x \mapsto \max(x, 0)$ on an interval $x \in [-R,R]$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, approximation-theory

For $R > 0$, consider the piecewise-linear function $\sigma_R: [-R,R] \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$, defined by $\sigma_R(x) := \max(x,0)$.

## Question

Given $\epsilon> 0$, find a "low-degree" polynomial $P_\epsilon$ (the smaller the degree, the better!) which approximates $\sigma_R$ within $\epsilon$ w.r.t the sup-norm, ie.
$$\|\sigma_R-P_\epsilon\|_\infty := \max_{x \in [-R,R]}|\sigma_R(x)-P_\epsilon(x)| \le \epsilon.
$$

## Observations

Here is a graphical illustration of such an approximation.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is done by using [Remes's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). It is implemented in Mathematica's command MiniMaxApproximation[]. Below is an image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook, giving a polynomial approximation of degree $10$. (Click on the image to see it better.) The quality of the approximation seems substantially better than in your picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, and for Ramez algorithm. My interest for the question is almost purely analytical. In particular, for a fixed sup-norm accuracy $\epsilon$, I'm interested in degree of the best polynomial approximation (+ existence), in terms of $R$ and $epsilon$. Intuitively it should be something like $\text{poly}(R,1/\epsilon)$ or even $\text{poly}(R,\log(1/\epsilon))$.

Comment: According to Bernstein, for polynomials of degree $2n$, and $R=1$, one has $\epsilon\sim C/n$ with $0.278\le C\le0.286$ (check the link in my answer)

Comment: Great. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: (so on $[-R,R]$ the degree is $\sim 2CR/\epsilon$)

Answer (score 13):

Subtracting $x/2$, and rescaling, the problem is reduced to the best uniform approximation of $|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ by polynomials, a problem already considered by Bernstein.
According to Chebyshev's theory, the polynomial of degree $\le n$ that minimizes the uniform distance on $[-1,1]$ from the absolute value function is unique and is characterized by [Chebyshev's equioscillation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem). It is also even, by symmetrization argument. More details should be easily available in the literature; for instance, these [notes](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr16.pdf) devote the whole chapter 3 exactly to the problem.

Comment: Also relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295676/approximating-the-x-function