# Smooth approximation of the $\max\{0,x\}$ function with controlled derivatives

Tags: sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, smoothness, lipschitz-spaces

**Motivation/Hand-Wavy Question:**
In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335736/low-degree-polynomial-approximation-of-the-piecewise-linear-function-x-mapsto), it was asked what the best local approximation of $f(x):=\max\{0,x\}$ is by a *polynomial* of a given degree; with the answer provided by Chebyshev's [Equioscillation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem).  Instead, I'm looking for a smooth (not necessarily analytic) global approximation of $f$ (which should be possible since I can now leverage smooth bump functions) such that $f$'s Lipschitz constant is also approximated by the smooth function's $C^k$-norms:

$$
\|f\|_k\,:=\,\max_{0\le j \le k} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \left |\partial^{j} f (x) \right |.
$$

---

**Rigerous Question:**
For every $\delta_1,\, \delta_2$ and each $k\in \mathbb{N}$, I'm looking for a smooth (not necessarily analytic) approximation $f_{k,\delta}\in C^{k,1}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying

- $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\, \big|f(x)-f_{k,\delta}(x)\big|<\delta_1$,
- $\big|\|f_{k,\delta}\|_{C^{k}} - \operatorname{Lip}(f)\big| = \big|\|f_{k,\delta}\|_{C^{k}} - 1\big| <\delta_2$.

Is such an approximation possible?  Atleast can I get $\delta_1$ arbitrarily small even if I cannot get $\delta_2$ to approach 1?

---

If no, what what is the largest $k$ for which this is possible.  If yes, can we also require that $f_{k,\delta}$ belong to the Sobolev spaces $W^{\tilde{k},2}(\mathbb{R})$ for appropriately large $\tilde{k}$ (given by the Sobolev embedding theorem)?

Comment: What is $d$ and what is the sense of the second condition?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry that sound read k.

Comment: You should clarify what equivalent norm of $C^k(\mathbb R)$ you mean. However for $k\neq1$ it hasn't much to do with the Lipschitz constant. The Lipschitz constant of $f$ is 1. So you want $\|f_{k,\delta}\|_{C^k}$ close to 1?.

Comment: @PietroMajer Exactly, I want the $C^k$-norm (now defined) of the approximators $f_{k,\delta}$ to be close to $1$.

Comment: On $\mathbb R$ it is probably difficult, but you could start on $[-1,1]$. There it seems possible to show that you have a problem as soon as $k\geq2$, considering a difference quotient around the origin (-1/n,0,1/n) say. When $k=1$ you are fine.

Comment: @username sure I think, for what I have in mind, I can restrict to arbitrarily large compact intervals.

Comment: For $k \geq 2$ this cannot be done. If $f_n$ corresponds to $\delta=1/n$, then $f_n \to x_+$ and $(f_n)$ is bounded in the $C^2$ norm. By Ascoli-Arzela' $f_n \to x_+$ in $C^1([-1,1])$.

Comment: Also, by the Mean Value theorem, for any $g\in C^2$ and $x\ge0$, one has $g(x)-2g(0)+g(-x)=g’’(s)x^2$ for some $|s|\le x$. So if $|g(x)-x_+|\le\delta$ and $g’’\le1+\delta$, you get an inequality $x-4\delta\le (1+\delta)x^2$ for all $x\ge0$, which implies $\delta>1/16$.

Comment: So for $k\ge2$ you can’t take $\delta$ smaller than $1/16$.

Comment: But I guess if I would decouple the first two conditions into two errors, $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ then could get the first error arbitrarily small even if the second is stuck above 1/16?

Comment: As explained in the answer, this isn't enough. Even if you allow $\delta_2$ to be $200$ it won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider $[-1,1]$ instead.

**Lemma 1**. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $f_\epsilon\in C^{\infty}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$,
a bijection from $\left[0,1\right]$ onto itself, such that
\begin{align*}
f_\epsilon(0) & =0,\\
f_\epsilon (1) & =1,\\
\forall k\in\mathbb{N},k\geq1,f_\epsilon^{(k)}\left(0\right)=f_\epsilon^{(k)}\left(1\right) & =0,\\
\sup_{\left[0,1\right]}\left|f_\epsilon^{\prime}\left(x\right)\right| & <1+\epsilon.
\end{align*}

A constructive proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736090/cut-off-function-construction/4365567#4365567). With this lemma, you see that for any $\epsilon$, define $f_{1,\delta} = \begin{cases} 0 &\textrm{if } x<0 \\ f_\delta &\text{otherwise } \end{cases}$ then $f_{1,\delta}\in C^\infty[-1,1]$ and fits the bill for $k=1$ (and $\delta_1=\delta_2=\delta$ wlog).

For $k\geq2$ that isn't possible. Pietro Majer in the comments to your question has given a nice counter example, and Giorgio Metafune has explained why this cannot be for the same reason even if you only ask the second derivative to be bounded by an arbitrary constant ($\delta_1\to0$, $\delta_2=10$ for example). By Arzela-Ascoli, the sequence of first derivative would be equicontinuous and (up to extraction of a subsequence) converge uniformly in $C^1$ to $x^+$ which is not in $C^1$.

Comment: Amazing and super-complete answer; thanks all!